# Is gas limit constant for regular transfers?

Tags: gas, gas-limit

Afaik the minimum amount of gas, required for a regular ETH transfer is 21000.

Is 21000 specific to the protocol itself, or does it depend on the particular network?

Does it depend on custom data, attached to transaction (e.g. does adding more data make the tx more expensive in terms of gas)?

Does it make sense to allocate gas limit more than 21000 for a regular transfer?

Comment: What is a regular transfer? Do you consider it regular only if the destination address is that of an externally-owned account, or also if it is that of a contract?

Comment: @goodvibration sorry for the confusion, by "regular transfer" I was trying to say that I'm just sending ETH from account A to account B, no smart contract or something

Comment: And what if account B is a contract and you are not aware of it?

Comment: @goodvibration let’s assume two cases - what if I know it’s not, and what should I do if it might be?

Comment: If the destination is that of a contract, then it will cost more than 21,000.

Comment: @goodvibration what would you recommend to use to be on the safe side? if I don’t know if that’s a contract or not

Comment: @goodvibration also, if I’m sure it’s not a contract, can I just use 21000 always? or it depends? if yes, depends on what?

Comment: You can use 21,000 gas, and it will revert if the destination is a contract.

Comment: @goodvibration what if I want to be sure it works, what would be the recommendation? use block gas limit?